# runif on rnorm-generated data per-row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a simple table, with decreasing numbers and a column of alternating "yes"/"no".

```
dat <- data.frame(a = c(8,8,6,6,4,4,2,2),
                  b = rep(c("yes", "no"), 4))

| 8 | "yes"
| 8 | "no"
| 6 | "yes"
| 6 | "no"
.. goes down to 2 | "no"
```

I then generate another column for this table, on a per-row basis, depending on the "yes" or "no" using `rnorm`.

```
dat$total_time = apply(dat, 1, 
 function(x) round( rnorm(1, mean=ifelse(x[2] == "yes", 140, 120), sd=10), 1))
```

This gives me a table similar to:

```
| 8 | "yes" | 148.3
| 8 | "no"  | 135.9
etc.
```

What I now want is create another column per-row and for each row get a random number from the range (x-30, x), where x is the newly-generated number in the third row.

I tried:

```
dat$test_time = apply(dat, 1, function(x) runif(1, x[3]-30, x[3]))
```

but I get the error:

> Error in x[3] - 30 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

if I only try it with

```
runif(1, 0, x[3])
```

I still get

> Error in runif(1, 0, x[3]) : invalid arguments

But when I click on the table in R studio, it says that the values in the third row are numerical, so I do not know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` with `rowwise` which makes it very simple.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(y =  round(rnorm(1, mean = ifelse(b == "yes", 140, 120), sd=10), 1), 
         z =  runif(1, y-30, y))


#     a  b       y     z
#  <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     8 yes   150.  131. 
#2     8 no    114.  111. 
#3     6 yes   142.  113. 
#4     6 no    123.  105. 
#5     4 yes   152.  135. 
#6     4 no    91.6  72.4
#7     2 yes   151.  140. 
#8     2 no    129.  127.
```

---

The problem with `apply` function is it converts data frame into matrix and matrix can hold only one type of value hence it converts all the numeric variable to character and when you add a number to character you get the error. For example, see

```
"2" + 3
```

> Error in "2" + 3 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

To avoid that you can convert the number to numeric in the function of the `apply` call and then use it

```
dat$test_time <- apply(dat, 1, function(x) 
        runif(1, as.numeric(x[3])-30, as.numeric(x[3])))


dat
#  a   b total_time test_time
#1 8 yes      133.0 132.61189
#2 8  no      115.2 114.26407
#3 6 yes      133.6 113.91254
#4 6  no      123.1 113.96119
#5 4 yes      121.3 104.90344
#6 4  no      107.5  80.98989
#7 2 yes      146.1 139.92842
#8 2  no      112.8 104.24055
```

Comment: thank you!
is there a way to assign the output of the %>%  operator to a variable?

Comment: @blurry you could do `df1 <- dat %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(y =  round(rnorm(1, mean = ifelse(b == "yes", 140, 120), sd=10), 1), 
             z =  runif(1, y-30, y))` and then use `df1`.